# Swift: downcast a hard-copy object, got default value for instance variable?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, oop

I attempted to make an exact copy of an UIView subclass object, with custom instance variable, by serializing and deserializing it.

I assigned a different value than the default to the instance variable before making the copy.

**Why would I get back the default value for the instance variable instead of the one I assigned?**

Please see the demo code below.

Thanks!

```
class CustomUIView: UIView {
    var insVar = 5
}


extension UIView {
    func duplicate() -> UIView {
        let archive = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self)
        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: archive) as! UIView
    }
}



let c1 = CustomUIView()
c1.insVar = 10

let c2 = c1.duplicate() as! CustomUIView

print(c1.insVar)  // get 10
print(c2.insVar)  // get 5
```

Comment: No, no, no! You should never, ever copy a `UIView`. There's a good reason why `UIView` doesn't conform to `NSCopying`. Duplicate instead the data that the view uses, and create a new view based on that.

Comment: Your subclass doesn't override the [NSCoding](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscoding) methods, so `insVar` is not archived or unarchived, but as @Cristik said, this is not a good approach

Comment: Thanks @Cristik! Can you elaborate on the reason why it doesn't conform to NSCopying? Am just curious about it

Comment: One (quite) good reason: relative constraints to other views. What should the `UIView` instance do with those constraints once restored? The original views might no longer be around. And even if around, would it be feasible to re-link the constraints?

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11! Exactly what I am missing here!

Comment: @Cristik - Thanks for the clarification ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSKeyedArchiver` is not some magic tool that finds all the properties in a class and serialises all of them. It calls a `NSCoding` method, which does the hard work of serialising.

You haven't overridden `init(coder:)` or `encode(with:)` yet. This is why your property did not get archived.

I don't particularly recommend this approach of creating an exact copy of a `UIView`. `UIView`s are just a means of displaying your data (or model), so you should probably duplicate your data and then display it with new `UIView`. You could write a method like this:

```
func createView(thatDisplays data: SomeType) -> CustomUIView {
   // return a new CustomUIView here, configured to display that data...
}

// or as an initialiser:

init(dataToDisplay: SomeType) { ... }
```

And create all your `CustomUIView`s this way. Then you will have views that are almost exactly the same - the only difference is the data it displays. Passing the same data to this method is almost the same as duplicating a `UIView` isn't it?